# How Can I Match Work/File Titles With Optional Elements Using Python 3 Regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have an intermediate level of skills with regex—I've used it for years in a few different languages—but am having trouble with more complex expressions in Python 3.6+ where multiple parts of the query may be absent. Different parts of my regex are playing tug-of-war with each other but after nights of reading, SO, and work I have still not been able to match all of my test cases, which are basic file or work titles. Here is a diagram of what I need to match:

"""

```
Title[ *semantic* version][ | Container/Collection (after *literal* vertical bar/pipe)]
```

"""

Here is my code, stripped down into the essentials, the regex and some test cases:

"""

```
import re

titles = (
    'Title Of Program 1.2.3 | Project Name',
    'Title Of Program 1 | Project Name',
    'Title Of Program | Project Name',
    'Title Of Program 1.2.3',
    'Title Of Program',
    '2 Hard Bonus',
)

regex = re.compile(r'(^.+?)(?: ?)((?:\d+(?:\.)*)+)(?: \| )*(.*)', re.M | re.S)

for title in titles:
    try:
        match = regex.search(title)
        print('(1)', match.group(1), '(2)', match.group(2), '(3)', match.group(3))
    except AttributeError:
        print('Failed match!')
```

"""

The second capturing group seem to be giving the most issues, as slight tweaks to make it optional (eg, for test cases 3, 5, and 6) make it **too** optional and it never seems to get picked up. However, all groups seem to be heavily affected by changes in another, which takes me to the limit of my experience. I have a trivial solution to this using """`split()`""" and """`strip()`""" but need to solve it with regex alone since the regex pattern is part of a much larger dictionary of patterns that a single function iterates over. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should give you the results you want:

```
^(.+?) ?((?:\d+\.)*\d)?(?= \||$)(?: \| )?(.+)?$
```

It looks for some minimal number of characters (captured in group 1), followed by an optional space and a sequence of digits and dots starting and ending with a digit e.g. `1.2.3` but not `1.2.` (captured in group 2). A forward lookahead is used at this point to match either `|` or the end of string; this forces the preceding part of the regex to match as much as possible up to the separator if it exists (otherwise the `(.+)` can capture everything other than the first character in the string). After that, we capture any characters after `|` up to the end of the string into group 3.

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/98xKDH/2)

Comment: I had never used a forward lookahead before—that was the trick. Thanks!